# initialvalues is not shown in react-select when using with redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, react-select

I am using react-select for the select field. I have passed the option to it in this format as react-select supports this way

```
export const statusList = [
  { value: 1, label: 'Active' },
  { value: 2, label: 'Paused' },
];
```

but when i get the value from api, it is like this `client_id: 2`.

How should i now pre fill the select field? I have done the following way

```
const InputTextWithSearch = ({ children, input, options, isMulti, ...props }: Props) => {
  console.log('input value', input, options);
  return (
    <Wrapper className={props.className} style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Label>{props.label}</Label>
      {children}
      <Select
        {...props}
        clearable={props.clearable}
        isSearchable={false}
        options={options}
        {...input}
        onChange={input.onChange}
        onBlur={() => input.onBlur(input.value)}
        components={{
          DropdownIndicator: props.selectIcon || DropdownComponent,
        }}
        styles={SelectStyleSetting}
        isMulti={isMulti}
      />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

`initialvalues is like {client_id: 2}`

```
<Field
   id="client-id"
   name="client_id"
   label="Client Name"
   placeholder="Select Client"
   className="input-field"
   component={GSearchSelect}
   options={clients}
   onChange={handleSelectChange('client_id')}
   disabled={!!company}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From react-select docs

```
value props - The value of the select; reflected by the selected option

One of <Object,Array<Object>,null,undefined
>
```

You have to pass object which is part of array of objects you have provided as option prop for Select component or null/undefined for empty selection

To be specific in your case you should pass

```
 { value: 2, label: 'Paused' },
```

as value instead of `{client_id: 2}`